# How to add the values of two similar dates which is in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i add the values of two similar dates values into one

for example:

```
2019-15-07  120
2019-16-07  152
2019-16-07  120
2019-17-07  100
```

I want to add the date  values of **2019-17-07**  into one for example **2019-17-07 152+120**. That is **2019-17-07 272**. Thank you.

to check i use the code:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*)
FROM getProcess
GROUP BY Date
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

which shows which is repeated date.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of count just perform `SUM`:

```
SELECT date, SUM([myvalue])
FROM getProcess
GROUP BY Date
```

If yo want to materialize the data and clear duplicates, you can store the above result in temporary table, then `delete` the found records and insert the them with the aggregate value:

```
SELECT date, SUM([myvalue]) [myvalue]
INTO #datasource
FROM getProcess
GROUP BY Date
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )

DELETE [dbo].[mytable] 
FROM [dbo].[mytable] MT
INNER JOIN #datasource DS
    ON MT.[date] = DS.[date]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[mytable]
SELECT *
FROM #datasource
```